# Do widow mines splash ground units when targeting air units?

Tags: starcraft-2

I just played a monobattle, where I went widow mines.

A teammate told me to not to burrow my mines in his mineral lines because of their splash, but the only units they had for harassment were air units. So my question is, **if a widow mine targets an air unit, would it also cause splash damage to ground units underneath it?**

For example, if a bunch of mutalisks come fly on top of my mineral line, and my widow mine fires at them while on top of my workers, would my workers also be damaged?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yup, Widow Mine damage splashes Ground if it hits air targets and vice versa.

Behold: a Raven directly atop an SCV!

[image]

After launching a missile at the Raven:

[image]

You'll notice the SCV is damaged, and both units have retreated after being damaged (hence the rotated model).